# Where does Alacarte store the file with the edited menus?

Tags: alacarte

I'm trying to import some settings unto a new machine, I've edit the Menus and removed some categories and removed some entries but I don't know where does Alacarte stores the file which contains all of that information.

How can I find this file (if it exists)? or How can I Import my custom menu settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there's a dedicated file managing menu associations centrally. Alacarte operates by modifying applications' `.desktop` files, so you might want to back up these folders:

```
~/.local/share/applications
/usr/local/share/applications
/usr/share/applications
```

Comment: I just thought it might be helpful to add to this that if you *create* a launcher in Alacarte it will go specifically in `~/.local/share/applications` with a (somewhat unhelpful) filename like `alacarte-made.desktop`, `alacarte-made1.desktop`, `alacarte-made2.desktop`, etc.

Comment: the filenames was driving me up the wall!  I have no idea why it can't name the file after the application.  Thanks for the hint though. :)