# Are there any GUI apps that can create .desktop files?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, .desktop

My question is simple. **Is there any fast and easy way of creating .desktop files for shortcuts?**

For example, I think you can right click and create .desktop shortcuts in Linux Mint.

I already know how to create them from a text editor like this:

```
[Desktop Entry] Type=Application 
Name=Eclipse Comment=Eclipse IDE
Icon=/home/jahedev/dev/eclipse-std/icon.png
Exec=/home/jahedev/dev/eclipse-std/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
Name[en_US]=Eclipse
```

**So are there any GUI apps that can do this?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Comment: I wish I could just right click the executable and do it. Oh wait you can http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/#arronax-als-erweiterung-fur-nautilus

Answer (score 33):

Have a look at my project, [Arronax](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/arronax/):

[image: launcher creation dialog]

It's available as a plugin for Nautilus and as a standalone application.

To install, open a terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/stable 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arronax
nautilus -q
```

Comment: How do I install this? I couldn't figure out the PPA stuff, and when I download the tarball all I get is a bunch of python files with no explanation.

Comment: That's the most comprehensive GUI I've seen around there, thanks! (supports categories, MIME types, etc.)

Comment: FYI - As of now, the PPA hasn't been updated to work with any Ubuntu newer than 22.10. Installing onto 23.10 from the `.deb`s on his page throws Python errors.

Answer (score 23):

You can try [**alacarte (Main Menu)**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/alacarte/):

> Alacarte is an easy-to-use menu editor for GNOME that can add and edit new entries and menus. It works with the freedesktop.org menu specification and should work with any desktop environment that uses the spec.

By default, is not installed. From terminal, you can install it using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Comment: This does not appear to be an application for creating .desktop files.

Comment: @JackM - It seems Alacarte `does` create `.desktop` files, namely in `~/.local/share/applications`, only with odd names like alacarte-made.desktop, alacarte-made1.desktop, alacarte-made2.desktop etc, as stated in a comment under [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/229277/925128).

Answer (score 17):

On Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 there's `gnome-desktop-item-edit` which comes as part of the `gnome-panel` package:

[image]

You could integrate this into your file manager with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/.local/share/applications
```

Generic installation instructions for Nautilus scripts: [How can I install a Nautilus script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236414/how-can-i-install-a-nautilus-script)

Answer (score 11):

For the Xfce desktop environment there is `exo-desktop-item-edit`, it works similar to it's Gnome counterpart:

```
exo-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/.local/share/applications
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: in order to create the launcher at any specified location in Thunar: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518827/341192

Answer (score 1):

For those looking for a minimalistic option, you can take a look at [**desktop-entry-creator**](https://github.com/faheel/desktop-entry-creator) that I created.

[image: s]

On Ubuntu you can install it by first installing the dependencies:

```
sudo apt install python3-dev libcairo2 libcairo-dev python3-cairo libgirepository-1.0-1 libgirepository1.0-dev libcairo-gobject2
```

and then install the app from PyPI using `pip` (or your favourite tool):

```
python3 -m pip install --user desktop-entry-creator
```

For the first time you can launch it from the CLI by running:

```
desktop-entry-creator
```

and for future runs, you can create a desktop file for it from within itself!