# Install libgluezilla & create .desktop in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: wine, kubuntu

First question : How to install libgluezilla?
I have installed Wine and try to run an .exe , but it says 'libgluezilla not found. To have webbrowser support, you need libgluezilla installed'. Then, I run this command 'sudo apt-get install libgluezilla' and Package libgluezilla is not available.

Second question : How can I make a .desktop file instead of creating widgets?
In Linux Mint 16 KDE when I right click program in Application Launcher > Add to desktop, it automatically creates a .desktop file, but in Kubuntu 14.04, it creates a widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `apt-cache search libgluezilla` to find the correct package.

You should see something like:
`libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil - Mono Web Browser library (for CLI 4.0)`

Install the package listed.

For the second part, see [Are there any GUI apps that can create .desktop files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457617/)

Comment: I already had this package installed. The libgluezilla error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

I use `alacarte` which is absolutely sufficient for my purposes. You can get it by just running the following command in your terminal:

```
apt install alacarte
```

With this nice tool you can easily manage menu and desktop shortcuts. It has a graphical interface and is really easy to use. For example, you can customize the commands according to your needs by adding arguments, or use your own icons, and so on. You can also customize the existing shortcuts. At the end it will generate the desired `.desktop` file for you. So you can easily launch applications or command line programs via an icon.

For more information take a look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

Btw: The `alacarte` package is also aviable in other Distros, too. Just in case, [here](https://pkgs.org/download/alacarte) you can download the package manually.